# combine multiple pdfs in linux using script?

Tags: linux, pdf

I want to save/download pdfs from X website and then combined all those pdfs into one, so that it is easy for me to see all of them at once.

What I did,

1. get pdfs from website

   ```
   wget -r -l1 -A.pdf --no-parent http://linktoX
   ```
2. combine pdfs into one

   ```
   gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=Combined_`date +%F`.pdf -dBATCH file1.pdf file2.pdf file3.pdf
   ```

My question/problem is, I thought of automating whole this in one script, so that I don't have to do this everyday. Here new pdfs are added daily in X.

So, how can I do step 2 above, without giving full list of all the pdfs, i tried doing `file*.pdf` in step2; but it combined all pdfs in random order.

Next problem is, total number of file*.pdf is not same everyday, sometimes 5 pdfs sometimes 10...but nice thing is it is named in order file1.pdf file2.pdf ...

So, I need some help to complete above step 2, such that all pdfs are combined in order and I dont have to give name of each pdf explicitly

Thanks.

UPDATE:
This solved the problem

```
pdftk `ls -rt kanti*.pdf` cat output Kanti.pdf
```

I did `ls -rt` as `file1.pdf` was downloaded first, and then `file2.pdf` and so on...just doing `ls -t` put `file20.pdf` in the start and `file1.pdf` in last...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of file*.pdf, you can output the list of files that you want with another command by using backticks e.g. `ls ...` as in chmeee's answer.  You should be able to use your original ghostscript command like this:

This will sort the files by modify date, oldest first:

```
gs [...] `ls -rt file*pdf`
```

This will sort them numerically, starting with the 5th character:

```
gs [...] `ls | sort --key=1.5 -g`
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/) and use sort like this:

```
pdftk `ls files*pdf | sort` cat joined.pdf
```

Comment: Sorting outputs something like this 
kanti10.pdf
kanti12.pdf
...
kanti19.pdf
kanti1.pdf
kanti20.pdf
kanti2.pdf
kanti3.pdf
...
kanti8.pdf
kanti9.pdf which is not what I want. Is there anyway to sort by modified time, then it might solve the problem ??

Comment: I want to combine file in this order file1.pdf...file9.pdf file10.pdf file11.pdf and so on...

Comment: The part between the backticks \`ls ... \` just needs to output in the order that you want. The -t option to ls will sort by modified time, -r will reverse it, so use \`ls -rt files*pdf \`

Comment: Thansk bmb, it worked, but I used ls -rt as file1.pdf should come first and it was the one that was modified/downloaded first.